# Eclipse Git - see difference of files and switch between branches

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch

I've got 2 branches of a project, the master and the dev-branch, both local on my computer. when i switch branches with checkout, in my Eclipse editor, the projectname adapts to the branch selected, eg. projectname [dev] and i can also see the file with the difference marked with a *.

but:
the file doesn't change at all when i'm switching between the branches. i expected something like, i checkout the master and see the file like it's saved in the masterbranch, i checkout the dev and i see the file, like it's in the devbranch.

when i make a git diff HEAD, i can clearly see the difference of the files.

Do I expect something weird or is there a simple way to see the certain branch-files after switching?

Comment: The file is definitely supposed to update.  Does closing and re-opening it help?  My Java editors update themselves automatically.  If not, do you have any errors?  Window -> Show View -> Error Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i've got it, definitly my own fault. i change the file, make a

```
git add .
git commit
```

make the commit and afterwards, everything works as expected...